# Как в Excel сделать ссылки активным?

Tags: excel, office, таблицы

Есть вот такая вот колонка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По умолчанию, ссылка идет текстом, тоесть она не активна.
Если редактриовать ячейку - хоть на один символ, текст становится ссылкой.

В настройках отображения я не нашел этой функции.

Как текст превратить в ссылки?

Comment: Добавить колонку. В ней ввести и растянуть формулу `=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА(X:X;X:X)`, где X - столбец со ссылками. Выделить новую колонку, копирование, выделить исходную колонку, спецвставка-значения. Удалить доп. колонку.

Comment: @Akina, при ссылке на столбец создается массив. Ссылаться нужно на ячейку: *=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА(A2)*. Ваш фокус у меня не сработал - данные вставляются как значения.

Comment: *при ссылке на столбец создается массив* Это тут при чём? гиперссылка создаётся правильная. остальное семечки. *данные вставляются как значения* Пардон, спецвставку надо выполнять в ту же дополнительную колонку, а не в исходную, т.е. поверх формул, заменяя их. А потом исходную удалять.

Comment: Вставляются значения с форматированием (синий цвет), но перейти по ссылке не получится. О диапазоне: *=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА(D6:D7)*, выделить формулу в строке вода и нажать *F9*. Результат - видим две ссылки. Ввод диапазона вместо одной ячейки иногда приводит к ошибкам.

Answer (score 1):

Можно зажать ctrl. и клинкнуть по ссылке, можно еще кликнуть правой кнопкой, выбрать формат ячеек, и выбрать Все форматы

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы при вводе в ячейку текст преобразовывался в ссылку, должна быть установлена галка

`Замернять при вводе адреса Интернета и сетевые ресурсы гиперссылками`.

Искать ее здесь:

`Файл-Параметры-Правописание-Параметры_автозамены-Автоформат_при_вводе`

Параметр не поможет, если данные уже введены в ячейку или диапазон.

Варианты преобразования текста в ссылку.

1. Войти в редактирование ячейки и выйти по *Enter* (менять символы не обязательно). По небольшому диапазону пробежаться с помощью *Двойной_ЛКМ-Enter* не составит труда. Не поможет, если указанная выше галка снята.
2. Формулой удобно, если вместо ссылки нужно отображать какой-либо текст. В свободный столбец вписать формулу:

`=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА(B2;"к прайсу")`

`=ГИПЕРССЫЛКА(B2;A2)`

где *B2* - ссылка, *A2* - текст. Если отображать ссылку, последний параметр можно не писать.

3. Для больших диапазонов замены можно использвать небольшой макрос:

`Sub PasteHyperLink()
Dim r As Range, c
    Set r = Selection
    '
    For Each c In r
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=c
    Next c
    '
    Set r = Nothing
End Sub`

Войти в редактор (*Alt-F11*), вызвать окно проектов (*Ctrl+R*), создать модуль (*Insert-Module*), в нем разместить код.

Перед запуском выделить нужный диапазон. В диапазоне дожны быть только ссылки. Не обязательно, но в ячейках пустых или с нессылочными значениями тоже будут созданы гиперссылки (ошибочные).

Answer (score 1):

Господа, всё гораздо проще)) Вы создаёте рядом новую колонку. заходите в верхнюю строку и применяете к ней значение: Ссылки и массивы - Гиперссылка. Далее в строку 1 ставите значение первой ячейки столбца ваших "псевдоссылок", во вторую строку ставите ее же. Применяете гиперссылку,т.е. нажимаете Ок. Далее наводите на нижний правый уголок первой ячейки нового столбца, т.е. той, к которой всё это применяли. Ловите тот момент, когда появится черненький "+", т.е. сможете нормально протянуть эти значения на весь новый массив, аналогичный значениям столбца с "псевдоссылками". Протягиваете до последней "псевдоссылки", т.е. параллельно ей. И вуаля, у вас появился новый столбец с массивом ссылок. Столбец с псевдоссылками скрываем. Работайте на здоровье)